# How to set python version 2.7.2 in the cmake?

Tags: python, cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt in which i have to pass a Python script consisting of test cases by making use of `add_test` as follows:

```
add_test( NAME My_test COMMAND python ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/win_testing/test.py )
```

How can i set and open "test.py" with Python version 2.7.2?

Comment: try to configure with -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/path/to/python2.6

Answer (score 1):

Use [FindPythonInterp](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPythonInterp.html) module to get path of Python executable to be used in `add_test`

```
find_package(PythonInterp 2.7 REQUIRED)
...
add_test(NAME My_test COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} ... )
```

Make sure that [find_program](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_program.html) called inside FindPythonInterp.cmake can found Python 2.7.2